# Periodic Patterns Identification in R

Tags: r, time-series, classification, arules

I want to identify temporal patterns in a time series.

```
structure(list(ID = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", 
"i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", 
"v", "w", "x"), `2016/01` = c(1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 
1, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA), `2016/02` = c(NA, 
1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, 
1, NA, NA, 1, NA), `2016/03` = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 
1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1), `2016/04` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 
1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `2016/05` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), `2016/06` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 
1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA), `2016/07` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, 
1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `2016/08` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 
NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), `2016/09` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, 
1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA), `2016/10` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 
1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `2016/11` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), `2016/12` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 
1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA), `2017/01` = c(1, 
NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, 
1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA), `2017/02` = c(NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 
1, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA), 
    `2017/03` = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, 
    1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1), `2017/04` = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, 
    NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `2017/05` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), `2017/06` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 
    NA), `2017/07` = c(NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, 
    1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `2017/08` = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, 
    NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA), `2017/09` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    1, NA, NA, NA), `2017/10` = c(NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), `2017/11` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 
    NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA), `2017/12` = c(1, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA), `2018/01` = c(NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 
    NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 
    NA, 1, NA), `2018/02` = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, 
    NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1), `2018/03` = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 
    1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA), `2018/04` = c(NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), `2018/05` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), `2018/06` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 
    1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA), `2018/07` = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, 
    NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `2018/08` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), `2018/09` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 
    1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA), 
    `2018/10` = c(NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 
    1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `2018/11` = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA), `2018/12` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    1, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

In the upper data frame individual:

List item
a has the same pattern as v
b has the same pattern as w
c has the same pattern as x

In the upper data frame individuals a, b, c, v, w and x have the same frequency - yearly.

The are some other cases as bimensal, quarterly and semestral.

My objective is to identify all this cases and classify all individuals with a time pattern.

I suppose that the package arulesSequences can be useful.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good start would be a full hierarchical clustering:

```
library(gplots)
library(dendsort)

# data preparation
dm <- matrix( as.numeric(!is.na(dat[,-1])), nrow=nrow(dat[,-1]) )
rownames(dm) <- dat$ID
colnames(dm) <- colnames(dat[,-1])

heatmap.2( dm, trace="none", hclustfun=function(x){
  dendsort(hclust(x, method="single"), type="average")
  }, col=c("grey90","darkblue") )
```

Clearly visible are all time dependent connections through the columns.
I included **dendsort** to bring similar clusters together to make ID related patterns more obvious.

[image: heatmap]

Also, only plotting the row-cluster lets you visualize the temporal patterns better.

```
heatmap.2( dm, trace="none", Colv=NA, dendrogram="row", 
  hclustfun=function(x){ dendsort(hclust(x, method="single"), 
  type="average") }, col=c("grey90","darkblue") )
```

[image: heatmap by row]

Adding a summary and k-means for comparison:

**hierarchical cluster**

```
dis <- dist(dm, method="euclidean")
hc <- hclust(dis, method="single")
# choose the height where to cut
# lower means more fine grained cluster, less member per cluster
cutree(hc, h=4)
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x 
1 2 1 3 2 4 1 2 1 5 6 7 7 5 6 1 2 1 3 2 4 1 2 1
# higher h means larger clusters, i.e. more member per cluster
cutree(hc, h=5)
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x 
1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 3 3 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1
```

**k-means**

```
# pre-defining k=6, has to be rerun to change k
km <- kmeans(dm, 6, algorithm="Hartigan-Wong")
km$cluster
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x 
2 5 2 6 5 4 2 5 4 3 1 1 1 3 1 2 5 4 6 5 4 2 5 2
```

Comment: Thank you Andre. But I have about 800.000 observations. Wouldn't a K means analysis be more efficient and explanatory?

Comment: As for the ultimate result I’d say hierarchical clusters give you the whole picture without pre-choices. The branches give you a good estimate of how your data is structured. As the datasets grow larger k means may be more efficient because of the predefinition. I see if I can add a k means for comparison!